# replacing word in shell script or sed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am a newbie, but would like to create a script which does the following.

Suppose I have a file of the form

```
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3

This is line4
This is line5
This is line6
```

I would like to replace it in the form

```
\textbf{This is line1}
This is line2
This is line3

\textbf{This is line4}
This is line5
This is line6
```

That is, at the start of the paragraph I would like to add a text `\textbf{` and end the line with `}`. Is there a way to search for double end of lines? I am having trouble creating such a script with sed. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can write something like

```
$ awk '!f{ $0 = "\\textbf{"$0"}"; f++} 1; /^$/{f=0}' input
\textbf{This is line1}
This is line2
This is line3

\textbf{This is line4}
This is line5
This is line6
```

**What it does?**

- `!f{ $0 = "\\textbf{"$0"}"; f++}`

  - `!f` True if value of `f` is `0`. For the first line, since the value of `f` is not set, will evaluates true. If its true, awk performs tha action part `{}`
  - `$0 = "\\textbf{"$0"}"` adds `\textbf{` and `}` to the line
  - `f++` increments the value of `f` so that it may not enter into this action part, unless `f` is set to zero
- `1`  always True. Since action part is missing, awk performs the default action to print the entire line
- `/^$/` Pattern matches an empty line

  - `{f=0}` If the line is empty, then set `f=0` so that the next line is modfied by the first action part to include the changes

Answer (score 0):

An approach using sed

```
sed '/^$/{N;s/^\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\\textbf{\2}/};1{s/\(.*\)/\\textbf{\1}/}' my_file
```

find all lines that only have a newline character and then add the next line to it. ==

```
^$/{N;s/^\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\\textbf{\2}/}
```

mark the line below the blank line and modify it

find the first line in the file and do the same == `1{s/\(.*\)/\\textbf{\1}/}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk's paragraph mode:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} {$1="\\textbf{"$1"}"} 1' file
\textbf{This is line1}
This is line2
This is line3

\textbf{This is line4}
This is line5
This is line6
```